# How can I get the first and the last element from MongoDB collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongodb collection called "Users" and I want to create a query to get the first and the last document from this collection based in a datetime field called `InsertedAt`.
I know how to get the first and the last element using `sort`, but I want to return both records in one query, like this:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId("65c656fd8651a89640db013a"),
        insertedAt: ISODate("2023-02-01T16:46:33.166Z"), // First record of collection
        name: "Bob Jhonson"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("65c4d88a2a06618ad4e972f4"),
        insertedAt: ISODate("2023-03-11T12:16:33.166Z"), // Last record of collection
        name: "Bob Jhonson"
    }
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do 2 queries, add them together. Or do one aggregate pipeline that does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks! But how can I add them togheter? Actually, that's what I'm searching now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just chain up your 2 queries with `$unionWith`

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "insertedAt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 1
  },
  {
    "$unionWith": {
      "coll": "collection",
      "pipeline": [
        {
          "$sort": {
            "insertedAt": -1
          }
        },
        {
          $limit: 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/5bboUHwymd3)

Comment: Thanks! I just need to change the `insertedAt` to `InsertedAt` and then all works fine!

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

1. `$sort` - to sort in the order you want.
2. `$facet` - by performing this stage after the `$sort` it will not perform a `COLLSCAN` if the `$sort` made use of an index on the `insertedAt` field. It will turn your collection into a single array named `docs`.
3. `$project` the first and last element from the `docs` array.
4. `$unwind` the `docs` array into two documents.
5. `$replaceWith` - to set the root of the results to the unwound `docs`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $sort: {
      "insertedAt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    $facet: {
      docs: []
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      docs: [
        {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$docs",
            0
          ]
        },
        {
          $arrayElemAt: [
            "$docs",
            -1
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$docs"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$docs"
  }
])
```

See [HERE](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NxB-g6Nn9Ye) for a working example.

Answer (score 1):

the response is not exactly as the format as you want but you can do it with only one `sort` and a `group` stage

test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MrHFclX3YiT)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$sort": {
      "InsertedAt": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "first": {
        "$first": "$$ROOT"
      },
      "last": {
        "$last": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Though it should work, performance wise it might not be the best.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit guess you're right, can you elaborate more? thought having one sort might be better than sorting twice

Comment: I guess the `$group` will make it slow. `$sort and $limit` can be optimized, see [$sort + $limit Coalescence](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#-sort----limit-coalescence)